# ¿Cómo corregir ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'trim') ? Angular 9

Tags: angular

Comunidad, saludo a todos.

Estoy tratando de arreglar un problema en Angular versión 9, pasa que me sale el siguiente error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'trim')`.

Básicamente lo que estoy haciendo es un buscador que cuando tipeo vaya actualizando la lista que tengo en pantalla con los resultados coincidentes.

El código del componente es el siguiente:

```
searchBan: boolean = false;
  searchKey: string;
  load_data = false;
  no_data = true;

// ...

searchInsideTable() {
    this.listData.filter = this.searchKey.trim().toLowerCase();
  }
```

Y con el método `searchInsideTable()` he intentando arreglarlo, pero sin éxito.

El HTML es el siguiente:

```html
<div class="col-sm-3">
 <mat-form-field class="col-md-12 search-form-field">
   <input matInput [(ngModel)]="searchKey" placeholder="Buscar en todos los campos" 
autocomplete="off" class="mat-form-field mat-form-field-fluid" 
(keyup)="searchInsideTable()">
 <mat-hint align="start">
<strong>Buscar en todos los campos</strong>
 </mat-hint>
 </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Soy bastante nuevo en Angular aún, cualquier consejo o solicitud de información para solucionar el problema será muy agradecido de mi parte.

Espero puedan apoyarme!

Comment: Inicializa la variable `searchKey = ''`

Comment: Ha solucionado el error en la consola, pero sigue sin funcionar el buscador. ¿Alguna idea de lo qué puede ser?

Comment: Agrega el resto del código.

Comment: Lo he colocado en un pastebin porque es mucho. Aquí el [HTML](https://pastebin.com/hrUktPHw) y aquí el [Componente](https://pastebin.com/wGEGyaky)